# attrgetter function in python 3.6

Tags: python, pandas

Perhaps for most of you this is going to be a stupid question but I've already been searching for a good answer in google and still I don't quite understand what this function (operator.attrgetter) does.

An example of someone that I know using this function is the next line of code:

```
df['diff'] = df['diff'].apply(attrgetter('n'))
```

where df['diff'] is a column with the difference between two dates, and the output is only a number series of numbers.

At this point I don't care if you qualified this question as bad as long as you can help me to understand it, thanks...

Comment: For an object `x`, you obtain `x.n`.

Comment: The problem with this question isn't that you don't understand `attrgetter`. That's fine. The problem is that you haven't explained what you don't understand about the existing resources that explain it, such as [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter).

Comment: Imagine the official documentation didn't exist, and someone had instead posted the contents of the docs as an answer to your question. Imagine that you then left a comment under that answer, telling the answerer to elaborate on some specific part you didn't understand. If you now take this hypothetical comment and incorporate the contents of the comment into your question, we will be much better equipped to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an example can help. Let's imagine we have a data frame like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1':['2019', '2020'], 'data2':['2018', '2018']})
df.data1 = pd.to_datetime(df.data1)
df.data2 = pd.to_datetime(df.data2)
df['diff'] = df.data1-df.data2
```

---

```
>>> df

       data1      data2     diff
0 2019-01-01 2018-01-01 365 days
1 2020-01-01 2018-01-01 730 days
```

Each element of the `diff` column is a `Timedelta` object:

```
>>> type(df['diff'].iloc[0])
pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta
```

A `Timedelta` object has the attribute `days`. Let's assume we wish to create a new column in the data frame containing the value of this attribute for each row of the data frame. We can achieve that using `attrgetter`:

```
from operator import attrgetter
df['days_diff'] = df['diff'].apply(attrgetter('days'))
```

The result is:

```
       data1      data2     diff  days_diff
0 2019-01-01 2018-01-01 365 days        365
1 2020-01-01 2018-01-01 730 days        730
```